# AsyncQueryHandler vs IntentService?

Tags: android, multithreading, cursor, intentservice

Looking at the source code for the stock Calendar app, Google uses an IntentService to do the content provider operations for the database. Is there an advantage to using an IntentService rather than a AsyncQueryHandler?

I thought that since a Handler is tied to the UI, if the activity gets paused or stopped, the Handler would also get paused. However, this doesn't seem to be the case: I created a simple content provider and AsyncQueryHandler that do nothing but run through a long for loop. When I launch other apps or kill the activity, the for loop still runs.

So is the advantage of using an IntentService for asynchronous CRUD operations that the service (being a service) has less of a chance of getting killed?

Update: Part of my confusion is how a handler relates to an activity's lifecycle. From my experiment, it seems that it's independent.

Also, for those not familiar with the stock Calendar app source code, the way it works is that to do a CRUD, it adds the operation to a queue along with a reference to a handler. Then it starts the intent service which pops the queue and does the CRUD. When it's finished, it invokes the handler via Message.sendToTarget().

So what does that extra complexity buy us?

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck with the same confusion. What I found is the IntentService will get killed with the activity. This also means that it will get killed on Orientation change. While an AsyncQueryHandler will keep on running(as you found out). In my use case I am updating my UI first without waiting for the database to update. So I think I am gonna opt for AsyncQueryHandler.

I don't know much about Intent Service(never used it) but as it is sending messages It might be useful when you need something from database to show on the UI thread..so that you know when the database was updated.